# Webextensions API - Can't get POST data

Tags: javascript, post, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to get POST data using a Webextensions API, each time when a page is loaded.

I added a background script, which contains the following:

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener( 
    getPostData, 
    { urls: ['<all_urls>'], types: ["main_frame"] }, 
    ['blocking', 'requestHeaders']
);

function getPostData( e )
{
    for( var header of e.requestHeaders )
    {
        console.log( header.name + ' = ' + header.value );
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, I get the following headers, which don't contain POST data:

[image: HTTP Headers]

Is there any way to get the POST data using WebExtensions API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer. I just had to use [`onBeforeRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest), instead of [`onBeforeSendHeaders`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeSendHeaders):

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( 
    getPostData, 
    { urls: ['<all_urls>'], types: ["main_frame"] }, 
    ['blocking', 'requestBody']
);
```

Then, inside `getPostData`, I can access `e.requestBody.formData`.

Hope it will help someone in the future.